# How to condition a cell that is within a value of another cell?

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, cell

[image: Screenshot1]

What I'm trying to do is condition the cells in column E to change colour depending on the value of column F.
i.e

```
If F3 minus E3 = <2000 cell turns red
If F3 minus E3 = <5000 cell turns orange
If F3 minus E3 = >5000 cell turns green
```

I want to condition the whole of column E with this formula

Comment: F3 and E3 will become F4 and E4 when moving down one row or just E3 become E4 and F3 remain the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select column E and click Conditional formatting --> new rule
- Click "use formula to determine which cells to format"
- and in the formula bar enter the below formula,

`=AND(F1<>"",E1<>"",F1-E1<2000)`

- select the red fill color and click OK

Now do the same for other formatting types,

Orange:

`=AND(F1<>"",E1<>"",F1-E1<5000,F1-E1>=2000)`

Green:

`=AND(F1<>"",E1<>"",F1-E1>=5000)`